# How to upload image in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am complete Newbie to Node.js.I just want to learn upload and showing images using ajax like i do in php.I found most of the tutorials tough for me.To get started I have tried using this code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


//all environment
app.use(bodyParser())



var form = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>" +
"<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" +
"<input type='file' name='image'/>" +
"<input type='submit' /></form>" +
"</body></html>";

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(form);

});
/// Post files
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Hello world');
       console.log(req.files);
});


app.listen(8080)
```

But am getting UNDEFINED for req.files.can anybody tell why?.Please forgive me if its a stupid question.And also help with some resources.Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Please take your initial statement out of the code block.

Answer (score 1):

req.files is for express v3, you are using v4.

Now body-parser only handles urlencoded and json bodies. 
For multipart bodies you should use an alternative.

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

For example with multer:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')

var app = express()
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))

/// Post files
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Hello world');
    console.log(req.files);
});

app.listen(8080)
```

Answer (score 1):

With express 4, [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) is an excellent way to handle uploaded images.  Let's look at a cut-down [example from Miaou](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/d5202230fc13cbf193ae0c010510113177604507/libs/upload.js):

```
exports.appPostUpload = function(req, res){
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers }), files=[];
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        var chunks = [];
        file.on('data', function(chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);             
            // todo : abort if sum of chunk.lengths is too big (and tell the client he's fat)
        });
        file.on('end', function() {
            files.push({name:fieldname, bytes:Buffer.concat(chunks)});
        });
    }).on('finish', function() {
        if (!files.length) {
            return res.send({error:'found nothing in form'});
        }
        // we can now work with the items in `files` like you normally would.
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);       
}
```